# VHDL UART testbench that send/receive to/from a software on the Windows

Tags: vhdl, fpga, uart

I need to write a VHDL code on FPGA side that can receive data from a UART port and write them to a SDRAM and send back that data to a UART port. a software is on the computer side that send and receive data. BUT, I do not have a board to test. I need to write a testbench to test my design.
my problem is: how can I communicate between Testbench and my software on the Windows? I need my Testbench read and write on a UART port.

Answer (score 0):

Testbenches are simulation models. They are "executed" in a simulator. A testbench drives the design under test (DUT) and checks its outputs. The results are shown as a waveform in a GUI window or if you have a smart testbench, it prints a result string like PASSED or FAILED. So there is no communication between hardware and software while running testbenches.